# Grouping by calculated value in Visual Studio Application Insights

Tags: azure, azure-application-insights

I am considering introducing Microsoft's [Application Insights](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/application-insights/) in a solution. I want to capture the duration of service requests.

When looking at the requests in the Application Insights UI, it would be nice to be able to group the result by customer size. The customer size would probably be a number between 1 and 500. Is it possible to create graphs where the service duration is grouped by intervals on the customer size?

A solution would be to define the intervals, when sending data to Application Insights, but it would be nice to be able to define (and experiment) with the intervals inside the Application Insights UI.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks Peter for your answer.  You can do couple more things to generate more insights

1) Bin in groups of 50

requests

| extend organisationSize = tostring(customDimensions.OrganisationSize)

| summarize avg(duration) by bin(organisationSize, 50), name

| project avg_duration, name, organisationSize

2) Generate  your own buckets

requests

| extend organisationSize = tostring(customDimensions.OrganisationSize)

| extend orgSizeBucket = iff(organisationSize > 500, ">500", 
iff(organisationSize>100, "100-500", "<100"))

| summarize avg(duration) by orgSizeBucket, name

| project avg_duration, name, orgSizeBucket

Answer (score 2):

How is the customer size stored? As a custom field?

Did you try out the analytics part of AI? See https://azure.microsoft.com/nl-nl/documentation/articles/app-insights-analytics/

I find these kind of questions hard (or impossible) to answer using the Application Insights UI. The Application Insights Analytics however is really powerful to answer these kind of questions. It can render all kinds of charts as well.

An example query would be:

```
requests
| extend organisationSize = tostring(customDimensions.OrganisationSize)
| summarize avg(duration) by organisationSize, name
| project avg_duration, name, organisationSize
```

To directly render a chart add

```
| render barchart
```

Only drawback is that these charts are only available on request and not integrated in the standard AI UI. It allows exporting though.